# Configuration http not running after installing mod_jk.so

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications

I installed: `mod_jk-1.2.31-httpd-2.2.x.so`

When restart `httpd` after updateing `mod_jk`

```
/sbin/service http stop
```

ERROR:

> httpd: syntax error on line 30 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: syntax error on line 2 of /usr/local/apache/conf.d/mod_jk.conf: cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_jk.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_jk.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Comment: You might be mixing 32bit and 64bit builds.

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct compiled version for 64bit system.